# How to fix "flutter has exited unexpectedly"

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing an app using flutter on macOS. When i switch to windows machine for developing, it shows the following error

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Sending crash report to Google.
Crash report sent (report ID: 4c15631f67927e73)
Crash report written to D:\hcbmobile\flutter_11.log;
please let us know at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

I have already created issue in this link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33645

The generated log file shows the following crash report:

### command

flutter run --machine -t lib\main.dart -d B3698Y11HA4122 --track-widget-creation --start-paused

### exception

FileSystemException: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'D:\hcbmobile.flutter-plugins' (OS Error: Access is denied.
, errno = 5)

```
#0      _File.throwIfError (dart:io/file_impl.dart:643:7)
#1      _File.openSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:487:5)
#2      _File.writeAsBytesSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:612:31)
#3      _File.writeAsStringSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:636:5)
#4      _LocalFile&LocalFileSystemEntity&ForwardingFile.writeAsStringSync (package:file/src/forwarding/forwarding_file.dart:147:16)
#5      _writeFlutterPluginsList (package:flutter_tools/src/plugins.dart:104:17)
#6      refreshPluginsList (package:flutter_tools/src/plugins.dart:297:24)
#7      FlutterProject.ensureReadyForPlatformSpecificTooling (package:flutter_tools/src/project.dart:175:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:478:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:424:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#12     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#13     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#14     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#15     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:415:20)
#17     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:196:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#18     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:396:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#20     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#21     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#22     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#23     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#24     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#25     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:356:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#26     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:111:29)
#27     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
#28     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:111:11)
#29     FlutterCommandRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:242:18)
#30     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:60:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#31     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#32     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#33     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#34     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#35     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#36     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#37     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:54:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#38     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:51:10)
#39     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:59:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#40     main (file:///D:/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
#41     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:298:32)
#42     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:171:12)
```

### flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.6.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.765], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.6.6 at D:\flutter
    • Framework revision e1a784ae3f (2 days ago), 2019-05-28 21:53:03 -0700
    • Engine revision 8dc3a4cde2
    • Dart version 2.3.2 (build 2.3.2-dev.0.0 e3edfd36b2)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: D:\android\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at D:\android
    • Flutter plugin version 33.3.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Symphony P7 PRO • B3698Y11HA4122 • android-arm64 • Android 6.0 (API 23)

• No issues found!
```

I have already tried flutter clean and flutter upgrade, but it did not work.

Comment: What is `D:\hcbmobile.flutter-plugins`?  Does it exist?  Is it readable?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to create a flutter project  using the command "flutter create " in vs code terminal , and I was getting this this error

What worked for me was I closed the vsCode and used powershell instead of vsCode terminal to create the project thankfully it didnt show any error

Answer (score 1):

I have got this error for the first time when I create the flutter project using Android studio. Then I try vs code and command prompt as well. I got the same error.

**These steps help me to fix the error;** 
1.Remove existing flutter folder.

2.go to this link: flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/

3.Install flutter again inside a new folder. (Follow instructions carefully.)  
**Do not install Flutter in a directory like C:\Program Files\ that requires elevated privileges.** 
4.Set environment variable again.

5.run `flutter doctor` 
(There will be no errors if you set up everything correctly.)

6.Create a project inside your project directory.

Done :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove .flutter-plugins file inside project folder.

Comment: i had same issue after setting up firebase_messaging plugin, this not work for me

Comment: Did not work for me as well

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was to simply upgrade flutter

Comment: Did not work for me