# Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: errno = 32

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-test

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "FileSystemException: Deletion failed, path =
'D:\otp.android' (OS Error: The program cannot access the file because it is being used by another program.
, errno = 32)".

How to solve this problem ?

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: look at this QA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56394520/how-to-fix-flutter-has-exited-unexpectedly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.